# Why 'AttributeError' when I am inheriting the base class already?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, inheritance

Sorry I am new to oop.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, idn, name):
        self.idn = idn
        self.name = name


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, idn, acc_no, criminal_case='No'):
        self.idn = idn
        self.acc_no = acc_no
        self.criminal_case = criminal_case

    def get_info(self):
        return self.idn

class C(A, B):
    pass


c = C(1, 'xyz')
print c.get_info()
print c.criminal_case
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "tp.py", line 25, in

print c.criminal_case

AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'criminal_case'

Comment: You would need to call `super`.  But your inheritance structure doesn't make much sense.  Where do you expect `B.__init__` to get its arguments?  You only pass two to `C`.  Is the second one supposed to be `name` or `acc_no`?

Comment: okay! but how do I invoke B's init in C??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost impossible to use multiple-inheritance without `super()`,so what you need is to use `super()`.

**super()**

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or
>   sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods
>   that have been overridden in a class.

Your code should be like this:

```
   class A(object):
        def __init__(self, idn, name):
            super(A, self).__init__(idn, name,'test')
            self.idn = idn
            self.name = name
```

And you will get the output:

```
1
test
```

In Python 3.x you can just use `super().__init__()`,and it seems that you're using Python 2.x,so you need to use `super(A, self).__init__(idn, name)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I access B's attribute 'criminal_case'??

Comment: @AmitKarnik `super(A, self).__init__(idn, name,'this is criminal_case')`,you will get the output.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not call `__init__()` for every class in the inheritance hierarchy. Instead, it simply searches the hierarchy for the **first** `__init__()` and runs it. Add some print statements to the code to see this yourself.

To invoke `B.__init__` from `A`, you would need to call `super()` yourself, along these lines.

```
super(A, self).__init__(idn, None)
```

But that doesn't make a lot of sense: where is the value for `acc_no` supposed to come from? Maybe you should revisit your class design.